# Meteor: allow predetermined values to enter a collection

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, meteor, typeahead.js

within my form, I have created a dropdown to display a country list as the user types. As it stands, they are able to select one, click 'sublit' which then gets inserted into my Posts collection via a meteor call. The following code along with this jQuery code (saved in client folder) is what allows this to function. Input id used is 'country.'

```
https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/dist/typeahead.jquery.js
```

My aim: To **only** allow countries listed in my 'country' variable to be inserted into the database. I would like this to be validated within my method function.

CLIENT:

```
Template.createpost.rendered = function() {
if (!this.rendered){
    var substringMatcher = function(strs) {
return function findMatches(q, cb) {
var matches, substrRegex;
matches = [];
substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');
$.each(strs, function(i, str) {
  if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
    matches.push({ value: str });
  }
});
cb(matches);
};
};
var country = [
"Afghanistan",
    "Albania",
    "Algeria",
    "Andorra",
    "Angola",
    "Antigua and Barbuda",
    "Argentina",
    "Rest Of Countries"
];
$('#country').typeahead({
hint: true,
highlight: true,
minLength: 1
},
{
name: 'country',
displayKey: 'value',
source: substringMatcher(country)
});
this.rendered = true;
} 
};


Template.createpost.events({
'submit form#createpost': function(e, tmpl) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var insertPostData = {
        country: $(e.target).find('#country').val()
    }
    Meteor.call('insertPostData', insertPostData, function(error, id){
        if (error) {
            alert(error.reason);
        }
    });
}
```

});

SERVER: **my method so far only throws error if user doesn't select a country. I'm unsure of the syntax to check the country value received from client against an array of values that I would like to list within my method** I am open to other suggestion to achieve this, please let me know. Thank you guys.

```
Meteor.methods({
'insertPostData': function(insertPostData){
  if (!insertPostData.country) 
    throw new Meteor.Error(422, 'please select valid country');
  return insertPostData._id = AllPosts.insert(insertPostData);
```

} });

Comment: Have a look at [Collection2](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-collection2)!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would proceed : first, declare your countries array in the shared folder of your app so that it will be available on both environments.

`lib/constants.js`

```
countries=[...];
```

Then use this array to build your typeahead client side and check against the validity of the country sent to the method.

```
if (!insertPostData.country || !_.contains(countries,insertPostData.country)){
  throw new Meteor.Error(422, 'please select valid country');
}
```

We use _.contains for this purpose.

http://underscorejs.org/#contains

Comment: Okay, this sets the validation, excellent.  How can I use the array from this populated constants.js file within the 
Template.createpost.rendered code? 

(I have underscore.js in my client now).

Comment: Just reference it using its name `countries` in your client code, ie `source: substringMatcher(countries)` ?

Comment: I referenced this countries in substringMatcher but it doesn't validate. I replaced it with country from my above code I provided.

Comment: Unless the countries array in the constant.js file is not correctly referenced. source: substringMatcher(countries)?

Comment: Please edit your code with the current code you have. The `countries` variable in `lib/constants.js` should be declared WITHOUT the `var` keyword to be exported.

Comment: in the constants.js file I have countries=[
"Afghanistan",
        "Albania",
        "Algeria",
"..."];

I have removed the variable of listed countries that was under the .rendered code (as seen from my initial post above)

Comment: If you `console.log(countries);` in your rendered code, does it log the country array to the console ?

Comment: No, and I'm getting an error 'Exception from Tracker afterFlush function: substringMatcher is not defined.' How is the constant.js file being referenced in the code?

Answer (score 0):

If it's just checking the value against an array, I'd just use the filter method on the Array.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

```
var countries = [
"Afghanistan",
    "Albania",
    "Algeria",
    "Andorra",
    "Angola",
    "Antigua and Barbuda",
    "Argentina",
    "Rest Of Countries"
];

var insertPostData = {};

insertPostData.country = "Albania";

if(countries.filter(function(country){ return insertPostData.country === country; }).length > 0) 
    {
        console.log("country listed");
    } else {
        console.log('country not listed');
    }
```

This filter function runs through your array and creates a new array based on the filter you give it, if the return is true it adds it, if it doesn't it skips it. So if the length is 0, then it hasn't found any country that matches the value.

Alternatively Meteor ships with the underscore library and you could do something like:

```
Meteor.methods({
  'insertPostData': function(insertPostData){
    if (!insertPostData.country ||  _.contains(countries, insertPostData.country);) 
      throw new Meteor.Error(422, 'please select valid country');
    return insertPostData._id = AllPosts.insert(insertPostData);
} });
```

Secondly add the array in a place that the client and server can see in somewhere like `libs/countries.js`

and add your array without the `var` keyword so it's not limited to that file:

```
countries = [
    "Afghanistan",
    "Albania",
    "Algeria",
    "Andorra",
    "Angola",
    "Antigua and Barbuda",
    "Argentina",
    "Rest Of Countries"
];
```

Comment: Thanks for your input Jeff, I will check out this alternative method but saimeunt is closer for what I require for now.

Comment: Hi Jeff, can you please expand on the the alternative you gave. 

I simply want to check on my method that insertPostData.country is equal to an of the item listed in an array on the server side.